SQL Query for to compare each row with other column values and if yes print other column name
Input:
col1    Col2    Col3
----   ------   -----
R1  Rajesh  R1
R2  Rohan   R2
R3  venkat  R3
R4  Total   R1
R4  Total   R2
R4  Total   R3

Output:
Col1   Col2    Col3  Col4
----   ----   -----  ----
R1  Rajesh  R1   Rajesh
R2  Rohan   R2   Rohan
R3  venkat  R3   Venkat
R4  Total   R1   Rajesh
R4  Total   R2   Rohan
R4  Total   R3   Venkat

I need dynamic sql query for above expected result.Please help.
SQL Query Problem statement

Do a self join.

Here is an example using Self-Join as jarlh reccomended
SELECT a.* , b.Col2 as Col4
FROM Example a
LEFT JOIN Example b on a.Col3=b.Col1

fiddle



col1
Col2
Col3
Col4




R1
Rajesh
R1
Rajesh


R2
Rohan
R2
Rohan


R3
venkat
R3
venkat


R4
Total
R1
Rajesh


R4
Total
R2
Rohan


R4
Total
R3
venkat




Inner join will eliminate records if col1 doesn't have a corresponding entry in col3.   This may be fine, it may not be. Just raising awareness.

Good point. I changed it to LEFT.

A different approach using an inline view and correlation.
Demo DBFiddleUK - using MySQL as DB.
SELECT A.*, (SELECT A.Col2
             FROM Example B 
             WHERE B.Col1=A.Col3
  ) as Col4
FROM Example A

Giving us:
+------+--------+------+--------+
| col1 |  col2  | col3 |  col4  |
+------+--------+------+--------+
| R1   | Rajesh | R1   | Rajesh |
| R2   | Rohan  | R2   | Rohan  |
| R3   | venkat | R3   | venkat |
| R4   | Total  | R1   | Total  |
| R4   | Total  | R2   | Total  |
| R4   | Total  | R3   | Total  |
| R5   |Pradhma | R7   | null   |
+------+--------+------+--------+

I added Pradhma to the result set to show what happens if we have a Col3 value not in Col1 or vice versa.
